# How are Permissions set on Cache Files in Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, php, permissions

I'm working with Magento 2.1.  I have a `magento_umask` file that contains the following

```
#File: magento_umask
000
```

That's a mask of `000`, which should give users, groups, and all-users/world write permissions to fils.  However, with this `umask` in place, Magento is generating cache files with the following permissions when run from the command line.

```
-rw-rw----  1 alanstorm  staff  508 Jun 28 10:52 /Users/alanstorm/Sites/magento-2-1-0.dev/project-community-edition/var/cache//mage-tags/mage---b3e_CONFIG
```

That is -- users and groups have read/write, but all-users/world have none.

Where does Magento's cache generating code change the permissions and/or override the explicit umask I've set?

Comment: I've been experiencing the same issue...just yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

Magento by [default](https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php#L62) uses Cm_Cache_Backend_File cache backend. And by default it uses 0770 for directory and 0660 for files.

See https://github.com/colinmollenhour/Cm_Cache_Backend_File/blob/master/File.php#L50

It is way file created with this permissions.

I propose to create the issue because for me it looks like a bug.

Comment: Magento uses Cm_Cache_Backend_File in Magento 2?

Comment: Yess, see link on 'default', https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/lib/internal/Magento/Framework/App/Cache/Frontend/Factory.php#L62